# Border Color for select list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I am using oracle apex as the front end to design screen and making validation using java script.

Created a item called select list. When select list is null it must highlight the boarder with color.  Below is the function which I am using to color the select list but this is not working need experts suggestion to fix

```
<script>
function formvalidation()
{
     //Select List Item 
      var f1 = $x('P1_COUNTRY');
      if( f1.value == "" )
      {
         f1.style.borderColor = "red";
         f1.focus();
         return false;
      }
}   
</script>
```

Call the above function on `onblur="formvalidation()";` event

Comment: What is not working? Did you add debugging statements to make sure that `f1.style.borderColor = "red";` is being called? Any error messages? What is the HTML for this script?  http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ is a great resource that shows you how to put together good questions that show you've done your homework and that make it easier for others to help you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that you're not setting a width for the border. You're telling it to have a red border, but without any width. You can also pass a reference to the select element from the handler.

```
onblur="formvalidation(this)";

// 'this' is the element receiving the blur event
function formvalidation(this)
{
      if( this.value == "" )
      {
         this.style.border = "1px solid red";
         this.focus();
         return false;
      }
}
```

Comment: Tried your method still this is not working only it gets focused on the item. still not able to make the boarder color.

Comment: @Sudhir post your HTML code here :D It will work and It has to work!

Comment: This method is working for text item but not for select list <script>
function formvalidation()
{
     //Select List Item 
      var f1 = $x('P1_NAME');
      if( f1.value == "" )
      {
         f1.style.borderColor = "red";
         f1.focus();
         return false;
      }
}   
</script>

Comment: i said to post your HTML and CSS not Javascript. Edit Your Question and There Add HTML and CSS.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#ex1
{
border: thick solid #FF0000;
}
</style>
<script>
function displayResult()
{
document.getElementById("P2_TEST").style.borderColor="#00FF00 #0000FF";
}
</script>
</head>
Here is the code   <body>

<div id="ex1">This is some text.</div>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Change color of border</button>

</body>
</html>

Comment: hahahah :P see this: http://jsfiddle.net/VPEbP/ done ! now don't forget to do something on my answer ;) Added somethings from myself, you can edit them :D and instead of onblur on select tag use onchange function.

Comment: I only know about HTML and not about APEX, sorry :D